# How to set number of workers in postgresql select?

Tags: postgresql

As the title states, I can run the following query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE screen_name='realDonaldTrump';
```

and get the output:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..87090.59 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=369.168..383.632 rows=1 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2   
->  Parallel Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..86090.49 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=312.741..326.849 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: ((screen_name)::text = 'realDonaldTrump'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1156140 
Planning Time: 0.065 ms 
Execution Time: 383.649 ms
```

Now my question is how can I transform this query to use more or use less workers? Online I found some parameters like `max_parallel_workers`, but I am unable to incorporate them into the query. I am running this query from pycharm -> postgresql console.

Edit:
After running the query from the comment, this is the output:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.00..87090.59 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=348.717..403.839 rows=1 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..86090.49 rows=1 width=122) (actual time=311.207..324.566 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: ((screen_name)::text = 'realDonaldTrump'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1156140
Planning Time: 0.563 ms
Execution Time: 403.856 ms
```

Edit 2:
After messing around with the postgresql.conf file and changing values of `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` and `max_parallel_workers` and then restarting postgres, nothing changed. Only later after I ran this query:

`SET max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 4;`

Did the initial sql query run with the requested 4 workers.

Comment: Why don't you create an index on `screen_name`?

Comment: Not inside the query. You either set it as a setting in the session, or a setting of the database/whole cluster.

Comment: I'm doing school work and we are learning about indexes.

Comment: Can I get a hint as to where I can change these settings? I changed the value for paralel_workers in my accounts table using pgAdmin but the query still executes with 2 workers instead of the specified number.

Comment: If you want to learn about indexes, then create the index and observe the results rather than taking the "brute force attack" with more workers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can increase `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`, or you can

```
ALTER TABLE accounts SET (parallel_workers = 6);
```

Comment: I understand the sql query as it is simple, but when I run it, the workers used (in the query from the question) are still only 2, not 6. And I can't for the life of me find `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` anywhere in pgAdmin, or am I supposed to look elsewhere?

Comment: That's a configuration patameter in `postgresql.conf`. Can you edit the question and add the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` output for the query after you ran the `ALTER TABLE`?

Comment: Edited the question with the output.